# tf.exe checkin command: TF10139

Tags: tfs

I am trying to use tf.exe to commit some files to TFS 2013 (it will be some plugin for our development tool). TFS server have security policy: every changeset should have link to work item.
We use the following command line parameters:

```
tf checkin /noprompt /override:"Automated Build Process" /comment:"-"
```

and the result of this operation:

```
TF10139: The following check-in policies have not been satisfied:
You must associate this check-in with one or more work items.
```

As I see parameter /override was ignored by the tool.
The same operation was executed by Visual Studio Team Explorer without problem.

Answer (score 1):

This situation was the result of using tf.exe in wrapping C# code. This is code snippet:

```cs
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(Constants.UtilExe, sParams);
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
//info.WorkingDirectory = <folder_with_processing_files> - this statement was missed

p.StartInfo = info;
```

This code start to work well with the specified WorkingDirectory.

It was our problem but the TF.exe output message in this situation was slightly confusing.